# multiple 'md-tab' have 'md-active' class at the same time when I switch tabs frequently with angular md-selected index

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tabs, angular-material

When I am switching md-tabs frequently, Md-tabs are switching correctly but multiple md-tab-item elements have 'md-active' class at the same time, So I can not see the tab's content which is active because it is overlapped by its right tab's content.

According to me, in angular-material, when we select a tab, angular first deselect the previous tab(hide previously displayed content on the page) and displays selected tabs content.  While doing this process, angular misses removing 'md-active' class of previously active tab.

Here is the fiddle to reproduce the behavior.  This is random behavior and comes while concurrent clicks.

Kindly wait for 1 minute after click on 'switch tabs' button 
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nq5hcdzw/15/)

```js
angular.module('firstApplication', ['ngMaterial']).controller('tabController', tabController);

          function tabController ($scope) {            

             $scope.boards = Array.from(Array(100).keys());

             $scope.data = {
                selectedIndex: 0,
                secondLocked:  true,
                secondLabel:   "2",
                bottom:        false
             };
             $scope.next = function() {
                $scope.data.selectedIndex = Math.min($scope.data.selectedIndex + 1, 2) ;
             };
             $scope.previous = function() {
                $scope.data.selectedIndex = Math.max($scope.data.selectedIndex - 1, 0);
                
             };
             $scope.switch = function() {
              $scope.activeTabsCounter = $("md-tab-item.md-active").length;
             }
             
             
            /*********    Here i am changing tabs     ****8**/
            
            /******** This is strict behaviour where I get the problem but randomly *****/
            $scope.switchTabs = function(){
            clearInterval(interval);
            var i = $scope.boards.length - 1; 
            var interval = setInterval(function() { 
               if($scope.activeTabsCounter == 1) {
                 if(i >= 0)                       
                $(".md-accent md-tab-item")[i--].click(); 
                $scope.switchTabs();
                } else {
                clearInterval(interval);
                }
              
            }, 100);
           
            /*********    /Here i am changing tabs     ****8**/
           
            }
          }
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="firstApplication"> 
      <div id="tabContainer" ng-controller="tabController as ctrl" ng-cloak>
         <div> <br><br>
         <button ng-click="switchTabs()">Click here to switch tabs</button>
         <br><br>
         Current active Tabs: {{activeTabsCounter}} 
         <br>
         </div>
         <md-content class="md-padding">
            <md-tabs class="md-accent" md-selected="data.selectedIndex" md-align-tabs="{{data.bottom ? 'bottom' : 'top'}}">
               <md-tab md-on-select="switch()" id="tab{{board}}" ng-repeat="board in boards">
                  <canvas id="canvas-{{board}}-1" width="1600" height="900"></canvas>
                  <canvas id="canvas-{{board}}-2" width="1600" height="900"></canvas>
                  <md-tab-label>{{board}}</md-tab-label>
                  <md-tab-body>Item #{{board}} <br/>selectedIndex = {{board}};</md-tab-body>
               </md-tab>
            </md-tabs>
         </md-content>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I am switching tabs in 100 ms but in our application, we are getting this issue in longer time interval also. We are emitting board switch event using socket.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, your idea is change the tabs programmatically every X seconds so...
Firstly, use angularJs `$interval` instead of `setInterval()` (that's because setInterval() doesn't care about angular digest). 
Secondly, you have to update the `selectedIndex` instead of calling `click()` event...
Finally, remove the active tabs check (I suppose that you added for testing)

I've updated your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/nq5hcdzw/26/)

**CONTROLLER:**

```
function tabController($scope, $interval) {

    $scope.boards = Array.from(Array(100).keys());
    $scope.data = {
        selectedIndex: 0
    };

    $scope.switchTabs = function() {
        var size = $scope.boards.length - 1;

        var interval = $interval(function() {
            if(size >= 0){
                $scope.data.selectedIndex = size--;
            }else{
                $interval.cancel(interval);
            }
        }, 750);
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<md-tabs class="md-accent" md-selected="data.selectedIndex">
    <md-tab ng-repeat="board in boards">
      <md-tab-label>{{board}}</md-tab-label>
      <md-tab-body>
          Item #{{board}}<br/>
          selectedIndex = {{board}};
      </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the problem is not solved. As you said I am not switching tabs in every second, actually, it is random and may be two click happens on same time in my code because I am changing tabs on a socket event which was sent by another user. Here I used timeout only to reproduce the problem. 

This solution will also not work. I can send you the screenshot.

Comment: I printed activeTabsCounter which is no. of md-tab-content elements with  'md-active' class. Which is the main problem because the count must be only 1 and it becomes more than 1 in a situation when angular material not able to remove md-active class from some tabs while switching.

Comment: Ok, I understand, so the problem is that you can't manage the selectedIndex? That socket event sent by another user, has the information to which tab you have to change?

Comment: Problem is that activeTabsCounter must be 1 in any case, Whatever I change selectedIndex. It is a bug in the angular material. How it can skip some tabs with the md-active class which was previously selected.

Comment: Hey, check this updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/5op3cgt6/1/). Here the tabs are changing in random order inside a random interval of time. I think that is a better representation of your problem. I you agree, tell me and I can update my answer...

Comment: My problem is not reproducing here. I solved this problem by manually removing 'md-active' class from tabs other than currently active tab.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP said in a comment, this was solved by manually removing the md-active class from all the tabs before selecting the new tab (through changing the data.selectedIndex in the code in the question).

For those of us who are not using jQuery in our Angular, the JavaScript looks something like this:

```
function fixMdTabsActive(tabsId, currentIndex)
{
    var tabs = angular.element(document.getElementById(tabsId));
    var elements = tabs.find('md-tab-item');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
    {
        if (i != currentIndex)
        {
            angular.element(elements[i]).removeClass('md-active');
        }
    }

    elements = tabs .find('md-tab-content');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
    {
        if (i != currentIndex)
        {
            angular.element(elements[i]).removeClass('md-active');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved this problem in my code by adding a `md-active="$index == data.selectedIndex"` to my md-tab definition.  In theory, this shouldn't be needed, but when I constructed my tabs, I would set the data.selectedIndex to the last tab, and the first and last would be active.  After adding this line, it mostly worked.  I did have one race condition that forced me to remove the md-active class as documented in the OP's comment and my other (community) answer.